# How to show a random string inside an array every 10 seconds React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, setinterval

it's working with console.log, it has to show on the front

```
render(){
 var myArray = [
    "Apples",
    "Bananas",
    "Pears"
  ];

  var randomItem = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];
  var intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    var timoutId = setTimeout(() => { 
        console.log(randomItem);
    }, 1000);
 }, 10000);
   return(
    <div>randomItem</div>
   )
 }
```

console.log shows a random string every ten seconds, but it doesn't work on the return()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Move the set interval inside of component did mount (or else you will create intervals every time the component renders)
2. Initialize state with an empty string
3. setState inside the interval this will update state and cause the component to re-render
4. use state inside the render function
5. Clear interval in componentWillUnmount

```js
class SomeComponent extends React.Component{
  state={
      randomItem:''
  }

  myArray = [
      "Apples",
      "Bananas",
      "Pears"
  ];

  randomItemGenerator = () => (
      this.myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.myArray.length)]
  )

  componentDidMount(){
      this.interval = setInterval(() => {
          this.setState({randomItem:this.randomItemGenerator()})
      }, 1000)
  }
  componentWillUnmount(){
      this.interval && clearInterval(this.interval)
  }

  render(){
     return(
        <div>{this.state.randomItem} - {Math.floor(Math.random()*100)}</div>
     )
   }

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <SomeComponent />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: How would you go about this using a functional component?

Answer (score 0):

```
  const [rndmItem, setRndmItem] = useState();

  const myArray = ["Apples", "Bananas", "Pears"];

  const timoutId = setTimeout(() => {
    var randomItem = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];
    console.log(randomItem);
    setRndmItem(randomItem);
  }, 1000);
  return <div>{rndmItem}</div>;
```

Comment: Change the time interval to 10,000 for 10 seconds. I changed it to 1 second for easier testing.

Comment: Add this to the top:      import React, { useState } from 'react';

Comment: It didn't work, but another answer already solves the problem, :) thanks.

Comment: useState is from webhooks that is used to manage state in functional components. Glad you got it working. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your react component render function should return just a representation of  *what your app looks like* in a given state.

So you should not make any changes inside the render function.

If you use a class component you can handle *how* your app state changes through your class methods and the React built-in life-cycle methods. Here is an example:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    item: ''
  }

  interval = null

  myArray = ["Apples", "Bananas", "Pears"]

  randomItem = () => this.myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.myArray.length)]

  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({item: this.randomItem()});
    }, 10000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval)
  }

  render() {
    return <p>{this.state.item}</p>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: @CERFECTUS it should

Comment: But it is a random string, so you can have the same word multiple times

Answer (score 0):

```js
class SomeComponent extends React.Component{
  state={
      randomItem:''

  }

  myArray = [
      "Apples",
      "Bananas",
      "Pears"
  ];

  randomItemGenerator = () => (
  this.myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.myArray.length)]
  )

  componentDidMount(){
      this.interval = setInterval(() => {
          this.setState({randomItem:this.randomItemGenerator(i)})
      }, 1000)
  }
  componentWillUnmount(){
      this.interval && clearInterval(this.interval)
  }

  render(){
     return(
        <div>{this.state.randomItem} - {Math.floor(Math.random()*100)}</div>
     )
   }

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <SomeComponent />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score -5):

What is it that you are getting? Also, use JSX when returning here. Try {randomItem}